# ASP.NET Razor Pages RedirectToPage without relying on folder structure

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing, razor-pages

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC application which uses internal redirects and looking around razor pages. A little bit of explanation the problem and how I solve it with MVC controllers. Here is how I'm using redirects in MVC:

```
return RedirectToAction(
    nameof(ControllerNameController.ActionName),
    nameof(ControllerNameController).GetControllerName());
```

where `.GetControllerName()` is a simple extension name that removes `Controller` suffix from class name. This approach gives me a freedom to rename controllers and actions when necessary, rename refactoring automatically update references and respect attribute-based routing. And no dependency on controller location/folder hierarchy. This works fine, because I'm using attribute-based routing.

Now, I want to offload some controllers to razor pages (`PageModel`). I'm finding it problematic to apply similar approach when using `RedirectToPage()` method. From what I understand, when redirecting to razor page, a full path specification is required, e.g.:

```
return RedirectToPage("/Section1/Section2/PageName");
```

that requires the following folder structure:

```
- Section1 (folder)
    - Section2 (folder)
        PageName.cshtml (file)
```

The downside of this approach, that folder structure can change and all references to particular razor page (for example, in redirects) must be updated to match new location as the result. They are strings and rename refactoring is no help in this case. I can keep the URL for page regardless of location by using `@page "/section1/section2/pagename"` and don't care about folder and file structure.

So, the question: is it possible to achieve similar approach in redirects like I do in MVC by referencing razor page class and then grab its URL from `@page` directive instead of relying on a strict folder structure?

**Update 1:**

Correct me if I'm wrong, but the problem can be more fundamental. In MVC, controller is invoked first, then it calls view. In razor pages, it is opposite: a view is called first and then based on `@model` directive, an appropriate page model is created. If this is correct, then it doesn't look like possible to achieve what I want.

Comment: Regarding the page life cycle, in razor page it seems that cshtml.cs executes first.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron then I was wrong and it should be possible to achieve my goal.

Comment: Why don't you use the Redirect method that takes a url rather than the RedirectToPage method which takes the path to the page? You can use constants for both the route template applied to the @page directive and the parameter for the Redirect method.

Comment: @MikeBrind I want to abstract from actual URLs. And MVC allows me to do this.